# How to define type as a list of object keys defined like [key: string] key/value structure - TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0, typescript-generics

I would like define interface in TypeScript like this, but I have no idea how to do this:

```
export interface SomeInterface {
  testProp:{
  [key: string]: {
    prop1: string;
    prop2?: string;
    prop3?: string;
    ....

  };
}
  requiredProps: ???? // <- here i would like to define type to be array of used keys
}
```

e.x. object:

```
 const value = {
    testProp: {
      orange: {
        prop1: 'test1',
      },
      kiwi: {
        prop1: 'random text',
      },
      lemon: {
        prop1: 'text',
      },
    },
   requiredProps: [] // posible items in array "lemon", "kiwi", "orange"
  };
```

I tried to defined **requiredProps** as `requiredProps: [keyof Pick<SomeInterface,"testProp"]` but without success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific type that corresponds to what you're trying to do.  You can represent it as a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) type, however.  For example:

```
export interface SomeInterface<K extends PropertyKey, R extends K> {
    testProp: Record<K, {
        prop1: string;
        prop2?: string;
        prop3?: string;
    }>;
    requiredProps: R[]
}
```

That will constrain things the way you want, but in order to make a value of the `SomeInterface` type you need to specify the `K` and `R` parameters.  You can get the compiler to infer those with a helper function:

```
const asSomeInterface = <K extends PropertyKey, R extends K>(x: SomeInterface<K, R>) => x;
```

And use it like this:

```
const value = asSomeInterface({
    testProp: {
        orange: {
            prop1: 'test1',
        },
        kiwi: {
            prop1: 'random text',
        },
        lemon: {
            prop1: 'text',
        },
    },
    requiredProps: ["orange", "kiwi"]
});
```

and you can see the desired error when you add an element to `requiredProps` that isn't a key of `testProp`:

```
asSomeInterface({
    testProp: {
        a: { prop1: "" }, b: { prop1: "" }, c: { prop1: "" }
    },
    requiredProps: ["a", "b", "c", "d"] // error!
    // --------------------------> ~~~~
    // Type '"d"' is not assignable to type '"a" | "b" | "c"'
})
```

Making `SomeInterface<K, R>` a generic type is more complex in that any values or functions that deal with them need to carry around extra type parameters.  You might consider only using the generic for code exposed to outside users whose input isn't guaranteed to be correct, and then internally widen the type to a non-generic version which is less safe but easier to pass around:

```
// code seen by outside users, enforces constraint
function externalFunction<K extends string, R extends K>(
  someInterface: SomeInterface<K, R>
) {
    internalFunction(someInterface)
}

// code not exposed outside, widens to non-generic version
type SomeWiderInterface = SomeInterface<string, string>
const someWiderValue: SomeWiderInterface = value; // accepted
function internalFunction(someWiderInterface: SomeWiderInterface) {
    // do stuff
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgZQgFtgBJFNLXAHgGk5RUkATAZzgAUoIw0YBPWsH4AaOACUGIJmzi0AfHADeAKDjq4qVjC48AXBODZozOmNUbLcMNzABGA9qjIA5gG41V9TZ4AmAPyOMM5I7p5ePmAAzIFwTq4elgC+8okaUMAAjgCuCBnMumCsBuIA2gC6KkkqKsZI2nCYrIQk5KgYOHgAvHB0UjLshXyCwmKSjMAs7AoAFCAGLWQUHTS0Y-IAlHBdiiAetRD18ABumAA22d2NzcRL7VTAMxYaWjq2Bs9e0JihwB-hXg0kQccAA5K87KCRADktDAXAANYIADuCH+8MswIMoKgP2YxE0jChMI0SThgLOwCIh3RGO8thB4KJ5K8ZIBbMsGRyeWABVsxTgpQARN9fkKxEKkaihZUkht9k1Fm1KJ0ngDXoVaV5MB9rAyDEKhXAyXAAEa6rFwQ3GsTYC36q1G6qwgFc3L5QoC4WYcVW02+oXYAPMGVwAD0YYYUG4UAAhACI3AALQp1Np9MZ9OKAB+uezCcjABV+LwwUKQ6DEOwkBB4E1WAgXEhMKbKZoIJoS3hQUKfXAAD5+o2DwNC0FVDY1ASlxYAdQQzDQypWVyVywe1HioTEW5c8gORzit3ni6gADVzpcFseF0v151tnBThdgG5w5GcLgwKhmDV0NkkGwGAEEOfo0GbM4ADEAKAkCkD6CYpjiYJXDGMCkNmVhbmXB5r1ae9VnWLZPkQZYIOgwDgMOGYsPw+5OknaoVH-Si4NI9pyJgqikBom9Txwzo8OAE873o3BiILOB8WQ7J0HQKogA)